# VB.Net - For Loop error: Undefined Var

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, undefined

```
 For i = 0 To R.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
         ' do stuff
    Next
```

Working with vb.net. It says that variable 'i' is not declared. Any solution? already checked if i have declare another 'i' var anywhere. it does the same also if i change 'i' with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) you should change your syntax in case you had not declared "i" previously:

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 5
    Debug.Write(index.ToString & " ")
Next
```

In your case, should be something like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To R.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    'do stuff
Next
```

You could also work with for each, which would be:

```
For Each row As DataRow In R.Tables(0).Rows 
    'do stuff using row
Next
```

**Edit**

As [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) said below, you could also turn `Option Infer On` at the beginning of your class and leave your code as it is. It would let the compiler define the type of the variable. You can use the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) for more info.

Best regards.

Comment: Better yet, leave the original code as-is and specify `Option Infer On`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it like this:

```
For Each Row As DataRow In R.Tables(0).Rows
    'Do Stuff
Next
```